# Add>Line resultant Line does not follow Global Axes

Tags: axis, lines

Whenever I add a straight Line from *Add > Curve > Line* it arrives in an empty scene at angles to the Global alignment axes. Is there an easy way to orient it along an axis?

Comment: press `Shift+C` to position the *3D Cursor* to the World Origin. Then when you add the line with *Add > Curve > Line*, it adds a line with one point at the 3D Cursor and then just delete the other point. And select the point at 3D Cursor and press `E` then `X` to extrude along X axis. Now you have a straight line along the X axis. or any along `Y` or `Z`. It's as quick as that. I think the reason it slants is to make it easier to see.

Comment: My personal habit is to create a Bezier Curve, because it's at the top of the menu, and hit 'VV' straight away. Then, for me, the rest is snapping one end to the other under the appropriate constraint, because my snap is pretty much always set to 'Vertex' and 'Active'.

Comment: Thank you for the info!